# What's the best way to show this particular data to a user?

Tags: web-app, info-visualisation

I have information on a user's data usage. Currently, if they want to check it, they see a table:

---

| Domestic in: x GiB | Domestic out: x GiB | Domestic total: x GiB |

| International in: x GiB | International out: x GiB | International total: x GiB |

| Total in: x GiB | Total out: x GiB | Total usage: x GiB |

---

(Pardon the bad drawing)

I was thinking about something like a bar graph with internal bars, like a bar for domestic and having it divided into in/out and the same for international.

Boss say's that it's too 'mechanical' and needs to be more 'visual'. I've convinced her to let both be implemented physically side-by-side.

Comment: Could you kindly make the title more specific? It's very generic and one cannot tell what the question is about by reading the title only (in listing pages). You should get better answers if the people this question attracts specialise in what you are asking - and a good title will help achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are alternative ways to show the same table.
[image]

Furthermore if you are looking for graphs, this is how Android does it.

[image]

You could get inspiration from it, and augment it with data recorded in domestic, international or from different devices etc using colors and annotations on the same graph. You can search for area graphs having multiple data feeds. This will help you superimpose different numbers and still give a overall picture of data usage. Preferably with horizontal limiters for warning and critical values.

Please note that Android gives the exact data and time period consumed upfront and does not force user to fish out the data from the graph. It is essential as many times users know the data limits and are interested how much they have consumed. You can further provide the remaining days in the plan and remaining data upfront if applicable.

*A bit of personal opinion, I have no study to back the following. Its just that I have seen Infographic making a lot of impact for the reasons below* If you are going for infographics, then keep this mind that users need to get accustomed to the way you are showing the data, and might not be welcoming for the same. Infographics make a great pitch to grab attention, explain concepts, marketing and sales purposes. Using that everywhere should be avoided.

Comment: Merqri great answer! Totally share your opinion about the use of infographics.